# Update without Internet?

Tags: java, git, operating-system, windows-10

I'm wondering if its a normal thing and if its possible for Windows 10 to update despite the fact that there is no internet connection?

I am asking since I'm worried that the update may have erased a major portion of my code I was working on before I can save it and commit it to my repository.

Edited: 
Blue update screen
[image: Blue update screen]

What my screen look like currently:
[image: Current screen]

Comment: Moral of the story: Commit _and_ push your work frequently, and do so before restarting Windows.

Comment: Update if what? An OS update that changes user data would lead to immediate uproar - so pretty unlikely. An online update without connection could only be done when update install files have been previously downloaded.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That one lesson I have learn long ago. Hence why I'm panicking as an update happen out of the blue. Also I didn't start any update.

Comment: @Fildor Well that the problem I haven't download any update file at all. So I'm baffled as to how this is happening as I was coding then the screen just went to the usual blue window update screen.

Comment: BLUE update screen? Never heard of that. I heard of bluescreen, though ... and had my share of them. Auto updates is one of the first things I get rid of when my hands get hold of a fresh Windows system.

Comment: I'll add a pic of what I mean and a pic of my screen currently for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

if this PC is connected to a network with other Windows 10 PC and they are all running the Windows Update Delivery Optimization, you might get the updates without direct internet connection.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-delivery-optimization-faq

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible without internet connectivity - there is no magical resource where Windows updates could come from. If you haven't restarted your computer in ages then the update (the update you are experiencing is a regular windows update package, usually [that's the normal setting] downloaded automatically and without you noticing it) might have been downloaded in the past when there was connectivity and Windows now forced your computer to reboot and install the update - that's a important security feature of Windows, since inexperienced users might never reboot their computer and that way never get any security updates.

Normally, these forced reboots are announced (either a couple of minutes or 60 seconds, I'm not entirely sure) before, so you have time to save your work and finish what you are working on. I can only guess you were annoyed by "another popup" and just hit OK or some other means of disposing that notification.

In the future, you can do the following:

- save to file/commit (and push) your work frequently (either save to file frequently - If the OS updates, restarts, etc... your personal files will not be affected or deleted or commit to a repository and eventually push the results to a remote like GitHub for example)
- Reboot frequently (normally, you would turn your computer off at night), so you are not forced to reboot in the future. Your computer's performance will also benefit from this.
- Use an IDE that automaticall saves, like IntelliJ IDEA - every time you stop typing it automatically saves the edited file to disk - you will never lose your work again.

---

Also, don't panick-post a not constructive question on Stack Overflow. Really, this question is objectively not constructive and you just wanted to make some air for your frustration, don't you? Chill, watch some YouTube or something while the update is installing, check whether anything is lost, and then ask a constructive question, if one results out of your situation.